# Why can't I use "subprocess" to execute "chown" to change ownership on a directory of files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to use the following "subprocess" command in Python to attempt to change the user and group of a directory of files:

```
   output = subprocess.run(["sudo", "chown", "-R", "user:group", "{}/data/*".format(workingDirectory)],
                           encoding="utf-8",
                           capture_output=True)
   print(output)
```

However, I'm getting an error that the directory cannot be accessed:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['sudo', 'chown', '-R', 'user:group', '/var/lib/method_transform/data/*'], returncode=1, stdout='', stderr='chown: cannot access ‘/var/lib/method_transform/data/*’: No such file or directory\n')
```

I tried running the following command from a bash shell script and it worked fine.

sudo chown -R user:group /var/lib/method_transform/data/*

I expect the ownership of all the files to be changed to "user:group"

Comment: `/var/lib/method_transform/data/*` This asterisk is a glob, and globs are expanded by the shell, not by chown. Change it to `/var/lib/method_transform/data/` and it will work.

Comment: That didn't fix the issue.